# Merging Word documents in R Quarto leading to altered margins in the output

Tags: r, ms-word, quarto

I am working with a `R` qmd document. With this document, I want to be able to print out complete reports, that include other components that are not R related (additional text that is specifically not supost to be generated by `R`).
So, the only way to achieve this (in my opinion), was to **merge several Words documents**. Namely, the cover of the report (that includes another page with text) plus the Word outputs that `R` would generate.

I'll provide the code bellow:

````
---
title: "Teste"
format: 
  docx:
    reference-doc: template.docx
editor: source
number-sections: false
execute: 
  echo: false
  warning: false
  error: false
mainfont: Open Sans
sansfont: Open Sans
---

# Start
  
```{r packages, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE, error = FALSE}

rm(list = ls())
#options(repos = c(CRAN = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"))
# Packages

ipak <- function(pkg){
  new.pkg <- pkg[!(pkg %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
  if (length(new.pkg)) 
    install.packages(new.pkg, dependencies = TRUE)
  sapply(pkg, require, character.only = TRUE)
}

required_packages <- c(
  "officer",
  "here",
  "ggplot2",
  "flextable",
  "knitr",
  "kableExtra",
  "tidyverse",
  "data.table",
  "readxl",
  "readr", 
  "dplyr",  
  "tidyr",   
  "ISOweek", 
  "reshape2",
  "ISOweek",
  "scales", 
  "stringr",
  "scales",
  "reactable",
  "writexl",
  "magrittr" # merge Word documents
)


ipak(required_packages)

```

# Second part

```{r}
# create empty Word file
segundo_ficheiro <- read_docx("empty_doc.docx")
sample_doc <- segundo_ficheiro
```

```{r}
library("ggpubr")
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm) +
  stat_cor(method = "pearson", label.x = 20)

source <- paste0("outputs/Plot.png")
ggsave(filename = source, 
       device = "png",
       plot = p,
       width = 32,
       height = 15,
       units = c("cm"),
       dpi = "retina")

sample_doc <- body_add_img(x = sample_doc, src = source, height = 3, width = 5, pos = "after")
```

```{r}
# Some text
text_1 <- paste0("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.") 
text_2 <- paste0("Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.")
text_3 <- paste0("Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.")
text_4 <- paste0("Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
text_5 <- paste0("Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. ")
text_6 <- paste0("Tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi. Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut enim.")
text_7 <- paste0("Quis varius quam quisque id. Pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus. Ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu.")
text_8 <- paste0("Leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam. Ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo.")
text_9 <- paste0("Arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus. Ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in. Elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus.")
text_10 <- paste0("Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel. Tristique magna sit amet purus. Amet justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet.")
text_11 <- paste0("Quis auctor elit sed vulputate. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam. Vitae semper quis lectus nulla. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.")

fpar_ <- fpar(ftext(text_1),
              ftext(text_2),
              ftext(text_3),
              ftext(text_4),
              ftext(text_5),
              ftext(text_6),
              ftext(text_7),
              ftext(text_8),
              ftext(text_9),
              ftext(text_10),
              ftext(text_11))

sample_doc <- body_add_fpar(sample_doc, fpar_, style = "First Paragraph")
sample_doc <- body_add_break(sample_doc, pos = "after") # force a new page
```

```{r}
library("ggpubr")
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm) +
  stat_cor(method = "pearson", label.x = 20)

source <- paste0("outputs/Plot.png")
ggsave(filename = source, 
       device = "png",
       plot = p,
       width = 32,
       height = 15,
       units = c("cm"),
       dpi = "retina")

sample_doc <- body_add_img(x = sample_doc, src = source, height = 3, width = 5, pos = "after")
```

```{r}
# Some text
text_1 <- paste0("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.") 
text_2 <- paste0("Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.")
text_3 <- paste0("Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.")
text_4 <- paste0("Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
text_5 <- paste0("Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. ")
text_6 <- paste0("Tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi. Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut enim.")
text_7 <- paste0("Quis varius quam quisque id. Pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus. Ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu.")
text_8 <- paste0("Leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam. Ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo.")
text_9 <- paste0("Arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus. Ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in. Elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus.")
text_10 <- paste0("Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel. Tristique magna sit amet purus. Amet justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet.")
text_11 <- paste0("Quis auctor elit sed vulputate. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam. Vitae semper quis lectus nulla. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.")

fpar_ <- fpar(ftext(text_1),
              ftext(text_2),
              ftext(text_3),
              ftext(text_4),
              ftext(text_5),
              ftext(text_6),
              ftext(text_7),
              ftext(text_8),
              ftext(text_9),
              ftext(text_10),
              ftext(text_11))

sample_doc <- body_add_fpar(sample_doc, fpar_, style = "First Paragraph")
sample_doc <- body_add_break(sample_doc, pos = "after") # force a new page
```

# Fourth part

```{r}
# create empty Word file
quarto_ficheiro <- read_docx("empty_doc.docx")
sample_doc <- quarto_ficheiro
```

```{r}
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm) +
  stat_cor(method = "pearson", label.x = 20)

source <- paste0("outputs/Plot.png")
ggsave(filename = source, 
       device = "png",
       plot = p,
       width = 32,
       height = 15,
       units = c("cm"),
       dpi = "retina")

sample_doc <- body_add_img(x = sample_doc, src = source, height = 3, width = 5, pos = "after")
```

```{r}
# Some text
text_1 <- paste0("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.") 
text_2 <- paste0("Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.")
text_3 <- paste0("Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.")
text_4 <- paste0("Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
text_5 <- paste0("Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. ")
text_6 <- paste0("Tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi. Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut enim.")
text_7 <- paste0("Quis varius quam quisque id. Pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus. Ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu.")
text_8 <- paste0("Leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam. Ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo.")
text_9 <- paste0("Arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus. Ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in. Elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus.")
text_10 <- paste0("Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel. Tristique magna sit amet purus. Amet justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet.")
text_11 <- paste0("Quis auctor elit sed vulputate. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam. Vitae semper quis lectus nulla. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.")

fpar_ <- fpar(ftext(text_1),
              ftext(text_2),
              ftext(text_3),
              ftext(text_4),
              ftext(text_5),
              ftext(text_6),
              ftext(text_7),
              ftext(text_8),
              ftext(text_9),
              ftext(text_10),
              ftext(text_11))

sample_doc <- body_add_fpar(sample_doc, fpar_, style = "First Paragraph")
sample_doc <- body_add_break(sample_doc, pos = "after") # force a new page
```

```{r}
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm) +
  stat_cor(method = "pearson", label.x = 20)

source <- paste0("outputs/Plot.png")
ggsave(filename = source, 
       device = "png",
       plot = p,
       width = 32,
       height = 15,
       units = c("cm"),
       dpi = "retina")

sample_doc <- body_add_img(x = sample_doc, src = source, height = 3, width = 5, pos = "after")
```

```{r}
# Some text
text_1 <- paste0("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.") 
text_2 <- paste0("Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.")
text_3 <- paste0("Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.")
text_4 <- paste0("Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
text_5 <- paste0("Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. ")
text_6 <- paste0("Tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi. Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut enim.")
text_7 <- paste0("Quis varius quam quisque id. Pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus. Ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu.")
text_8 <- paste0("Leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam. Ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo.")
text_9 <- paste0("Arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus. Ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in. Elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus.")
text_10 <- paste0("Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel. Tristique magna sit amet purus. Amet justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet.")
text_11 <- paste0("Quis auctor elit sed vulputate. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam. Vitae semper quis lectus nulla. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.")

fpar_ <- fpar(ftext(text_1),
              ftext(text_2),
              ftext(text_3),
              ftext(text_4),
              ftext(text_5),
              ftext(text_6),
              ftext(text_7),
              ftext(text_8),
              ftext(text_9),
              ftext(text_10),
              ftext(text_11))

sample_doc <- body_add_fpar(sample_doc, fpar_, style = "First Paragraph")
sample_doc <- body_add_break(sample_doc, pos = "after") # force a new page
```

# FINAL

```{r FINAL}

document_name <- paste0("Output.docx")

# FINAL

print(segundo_ficheiro, target = "Second.docx")
print(quarto_ficheiro, target = "Fourth.docx")

# Merge, then print the final output

read_docx(path = "Cover.docx") %>% 
  body_add_docx(src = "Second.docx") %>% 
  body_add_docx(src = "Third.docx") %>% 
  body_add_docx(src = "Fourth.docx") %>% 
  body_add_docx(src = "Final.docx") %>% 
  print(target = document_name)

```
````

(I'm sorry for the long code, but it is a really long report.)

The issue that I am facing is that when I merge all of these documents, the margins somehow are changed. I have looked in each of the word documents and none of these have the margins configurations what could lead to this:

[image: example]

The "First Chapter" section is an example of a section that is not be related with R. The second paragraph on this page is a phrase inputed by R. So why did the margins change?
Additionally, no matter how much I change the margins on the "template" doc, I always get the ouput to be like this:

[image: example2]

I want the margins to be wider, but I am struggling to achieve this. Does anyone know, or have a suspicion on why this is happening?
Any sort of help or insight is really appreciated!